# How to strech vertically the container of inline-blocks?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple menu for my home server web platform for multiple screen resolutions.

[Complete Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7k930teu/)

```
#menu-area{
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    width: 70%;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.menu-box{
    display:inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

My idea was that, as the screen gets narrow , the menu links rearrange themselves, and transform from a line to a column. That part works as intended.

However when the menu gets more than 2 lines long vertically, it starts to overleap with the content display area.

I can't figure out, how to strech the div containing the menu-box -es to contain them, so the content area can get pushed down and not overleap with the menu.

P.S.: If possible I only want to use html and css for this layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you comment out these lines in CSS - it works:

```
#head {
/* min-height: 200px; */
/* height: 15%; */

#menu {
/* height: 50px; */

#menu-area {
/* position: absolute; */
/* min-height: 50px; */
```

Comment: because if you fix the height of head or menu - it does not let it stretch to fit all the contents